# Applications of Boolean Differential Calculus

Tags: calculus, boolean-algebra, boolean

I've recently read about a subject field called "Boolean differential calculus", which discusses changes of Boolean variables and functions. This subject defines the derivative of a Boolean function, its minimum/maximum, etc. 
While the field sounds very interesting, I couldn't find much about its applications. I found a book by Steinbach and Posthoff called "Boolean Differential Calculus" which describes applications, but it's under a paywall. 
For any of you familiar with the subject, what are some interesting applications that can be done with it? I would also be interested in sources that are open-access. Thank you in advance!